# a function that is faster than printf

Tags: c, printf

I am beginner c programmer and I read that `printf()` is very sophisticates function that is very slow and consumes many CPU cycles. So I want to know is there any function that exists in standard pure c library and is faster than `printf()` or not and when to use that function and when not to use it. My goal is to write efficient code that can work on any computer and/or embedded system

Comment: It depends on what the output will be. `printf` formats the ouput, do you want formatted output too?

Comment: Have you measured that `printf` is slow or are you just parroting things heard from elsewhere? Don't try to optimize until you have something to optimize.

Comment: if you are a beginner, don't worry about performance. really, it's the wrong mind-set.

Comment: I want the output to be formatted

Comment: It depends what kind of formatting you need. If it's just for exemple printing text and integers you can make your own functions using `fputs` and `itoa`.

Comment: but 'asser' doesn't print text to standard output

Comment: helped too much thanks Michael Walz

Comment: @MichaelWalz `fputs` will be slow too, you can do it if you write characters 1 by 1 `write(STDOUT_FILENO, &character, 1);` or if you want you can write a buffer of bytes `write(STDOUT_FILENO, buffer, lengthOfBuffer);` that will be fast, but `fputs()` will have almost the same problem as `printf()` except that it does no formatting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

actually I found that `write()` is the fastest alternative to `printf()`
I have written 2 little programs that prints hello world to standard out
the first one

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h> int main() {
char* h = "hello world\n";
for ( int i=0; i < 100000; i++) write(0,h,strlen(h));
}
```

and the second one

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main() {
char* x = "hello world\n";
for (int i =0;i<100000; i++) printf("%s",x); }
```

and compared the run time of the 2 programs on my pc computer
the first terminated in 2.740s
while the second terminated in 3.071s

Comment: If you need performance, don't call `write`, `fwrite` is far better. `write` is a system call a calling it is mucbh more costly than calling a library function such like `fwrite`. The later will provide you buffering which saves you some costly `write`s.

Answer (score 1):

There are a reasons that discourages the use of printf.

1) printf is a function and is not likely to be inline-able, so as a function it disrupts the compiler optimization of the code around it. If you have a loop that does a lot of heavy lifting and you want compiler to do a good job optimizing it, then don't call any non-inlined function inside that loop.

2) The way stdio route out the content is very implementation dependent, and can be very slow. If you are using a development board to run the code, then stdio is usually implemented via JTAG. In this case, not only printf but everything through stdio are extremely slow. If you use printf too much, you'll hit the timing limit easily.

3) Your target platform may not implement stdio. This is common for embedded platform, because they are EMBEDDED in something else and might not have an easy way to route contents in or out.

And to your question: yes and no.

Yes: there are, trace utilities that are designed to be lightweight and fast and can be used as a faster alternative to printf, like GT_TRACE by Texas Instruments for their DPS's. Unlike printf, trace can be easily turned off at run time and compile time. When turned off, they take very little time.

No: trace utilities are not standard C. They are usually part of your target platform's SDK

Bottom line: for now, don't think too much about it. Replace printfs with trace when you move to embedded platform, if necessary.